# Returning text of HTML request in Python

Tags: python, html, web, urllib

So I think I've done my due diligence and can't seem to find anything quite right.

I'm trying to parse a text file from a git server (url ends in .txt) and I've tried using urllib and urllib2. When I do the following:

```
response2 = urllib.urlopen(url2)
data2 = response2.read()
```

what I get is html output. I want the plain text. I know I could use some external library (something something soup is beautiful) but I really want to keep it simple. It seems like I should be able to get the raw (copy-paste style) output of this page (which is expressing a text file) and not the HTML. I also don't want to download it from the server.

Thanks in advance Code Gods!

EDIT:

I realize now that I'm actually having authentication issues with git as well, so this looks like it is going to be more than a simple HTML-to-text deal. I think I'll look for another way.

Comment: What is the URL? What is the server sending?  What is the HTTP content-type (independent of the file extension)? Have you examined the traffic with Wireshark to see what is coming across the wire?  There is a lot of information needed before anybody can begin to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You must look at [`urllib.urlretrieve`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlretrieve)

The `urlretrieve` method lets you store the file locally to specified path/filename.

Thus, your code should look like

```
filename, headers = urllib.urlretrieve(url)
data = open(filename).read()
```